# Как создать <use> в <svg> через javascript?

Tags: javascript, svg

Помогите пожалуйста. Нужно добавить елемент `<use xlink:href="#myID" x="0" y="100"></use>` в `<svg>` средствами JavaScript.

Проблема в том, что сам элемент добавляется все нормально и все свойства все ок, но не отображается.

Элемент который копируется - `xlink:href="#myID"` уже присутствует в `html` (но тоже добавляется динамически), т.е. элемент `<use>` добавляется, после, (вроде все правильно), но не отображается.

Проверял - вставил строку `<use xlink:href="#myID" x="0" y="100">` прямо в код-`html`, но в отладчике в браузере и все нормально отобразилось.

И вот стоят две строки абсолютно одинаковые, но по одной элемент отображается, а по другой нет. Может как-то вставлять фрагментом кода-html, а не через:

```
copy = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",'use');
        copy.setAttribute('xlink:href','#myID');
        copy.setAttribute('x',0);
        copy.setAttribute('y',100);
        svg.insertBefore(сopy, firstChild);
```

Comment: можно весь код вашей страницы?

Comment: Нужен пример в виде сниппета.

Comment: Спасибо за правильный код. Дело было в одной строке - не правильно добавлял атрибут элементу. copy.setAttribute('xlink:href','#myID'); Нужно было прописать так:         copy.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", "href", "#myID"); Спасибо еще раз. Вопрос решен. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот пример добавления элемента `line` и `use` связанного с ним. И обе добавляются динамически:

```js
var  svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
    var  xlinkns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";

    var aLine = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'line');
        aLine.setAttribute('x1', 48.09);
        aLine.setAttribute('y1', 41.694);
        aLine.setAttribute('x2', 107.924);
        aLine.setAttribute('y2', 41.694);
        aLine.setAttribute('stroke', '#191199');
        aLine.setAttribute('stroke-width', 2);
        aLine.setAttribute('id', 'MidCLine1');
        aLine.setAttribute('stroke-miterlimit', 10);
        aLine.setAttribute('fill', 'none');
    var  g = document.getElementById("ledgerlines");
    g.appendChild(aLine);

    var  use = document.createElementNS(svgns, "use");
    use.setAttributeNS(xlinkns, "href", "#MidCLine1");
    use.setAttribute("x", "10");  // offset = y+10
    use.setAttribute("y", "10");

    g.appendChild(use);
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="ex1-3rds-quarter-s" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px"
 y="0px" width="323.333px" height="55.333px" viewBox="0 0 323.333 55.333" enable-background="new 0 0 323.333 55.333"
 xml:space="preserve">
<g id="ledgerlines">
  
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Спасибо за правильный код. Дело было в одной строке - не правильно добавлял атрибут элементу. copy.setAttribute('xlink:href','#myID'); Нужно было прописать так:         copy.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", "href", "#myID"); Спасибо еще раз. Вопрос решен. :-)